# VBA - Ignore part of strBody if cell is blank?

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have a VBA script made in Excel 2010 that sends me an email 30 minutes before a task reaches its due date. The body of the message "strBody" fetches the value of three cells to make the message unique. It fetches the Name of the Task, the Notes of the Task and the Due Date of the task.

What I am wondering is if there is a way for a part of this message to be left out if one of the referenced cell is blank.

In this template below:

```
"This email is to notify you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & " is nearing its Due Date: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "E").Value & "." & vbNewLine & "A wise decision would be to complete this task before it expires!" & _ 
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager"
```

I would like the following section to be removed if Cells(FormulaCell.Row,"B") is blank.

```
" with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & "
```

This is mainly a cleanup process as having an empty area in a message is far from pretty, and I am using this as a business tool with multiple people in CC.

Currently, a message with a blank Note area looks like:

```
Hello,
This email is to notify you that your task : Give Denise a Promotion, with the following note:   is nearing its due date: 02/09/2016.
A wise decision would be to complete the task before it expires!
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in an IF ELSE statement.

```
If Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value = "" Then
    msg = "This email is to notify you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " is nearing its Due Date: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "E").Value & "." & vbNewLine & "A wise decision would be to complete this task before it expires!" & _ 
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager"
Else
    msg = "This email is to notify you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & " is nearing its Due Date: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "E").Value & "." & vbNewLine & "A wise decision would be to complete this task before it expires!" & _ 
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager"
End If
```

Add in ElseIf in there if other fields other than note might be blank too.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with only one If statement with conditional concatenation

```
    msg = "This email is to notify you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value

    If Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value <> "" Then 
        msg = msg & " with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value
    end if

    msg = msg & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " is nearing its Due Date: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "E").Value & "." & vbNewLine & "A wise decision would be to complete this task before it expires!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager"
```

Comment: Another viable solution :) Very instructive, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would have an if statement to see if it is empty and then just skip over it. So instead of one line of code with all the &, break it up into different sentences. Check to see if there are any values in the strings, then append them into one string for sending.
It will add more code but will look better.
So for instance if you have a part B then your message would append to the sending sting = A+B+C
But if you dont have a value for B then your if statement will then skip the b section and append only a and c to your sending string.
Something like that would work for your purposes I think.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking - just I provided the code!

Comment: I saw that right after I posted it. Great minds think a like. :)